# Dynamic checkbox to hide dynamic inputbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm rendering a dynamic input and checkbox from an `array` object which is fine, however I'm not quite sure how to hide the `input` when I click on the `checkbox` relative to the input.

```
 function dynamicStuff () {
  var objs = ['Id', 'Name', 'Age'];

      for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        objs[i];
        var cElement = document.createElement("input");
        cElement.type = "checkbox";
        cElement.name = objs[i];
        cElement.id = objs[i];

        var cElementInput = document.createElement("input");
        cElementInput.type = "text";
        cElementInput.name = objs[i];
        cElementInput.id = objs[i];
        cElementInput.placeholder = objs[i]
        document.getElementById('chkBox').appendChild(cElement); 
        document.getElementById('chkBox').appendChild(cElementInput); 
      }

    }
```

**[Live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/cqUTr618AmgYmPTMT4XW?p=preview)**.

Saving on localStroage:

```
function chkboxCookie() {
    var indexOfItem = checkAllFields.indexOf(this.id);
    if (indexOfItem >= 0) {
        checkAllFields.splice(indexOfItem, 1);
    } else {
        checkAllFields.push(this.id);
    }

    /* it saves paramater name in the localStorage*/
    localStorage.setItem("checkedUsers", JSON.stringify(checkAllFields));
}
```

How do I hide the `input` that I ticked and potentially save that `input` name/Id in the localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/217/)**.

The `id` attribute should be unique in the same page so try to change the id of the input for example :

```
cElementInput.id = objs[i]+'_input';
```

And attach change event to the checkbox's where you'll show/hide related inputs:

```
cElement.addEventListener("change", toggleInput, false);
```

Then define your `toggleInput()` function :

```
function toggleInput(){
    var input_id = this.id+'_input';

    document.getElementById(input_id).style.display = this.checked ? 'inline' : 'none';      

   localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);  
}
```

To `check/uncheck` the checkboxe's based on `localStorage`, get the data first :

```
var localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkedUsers"));
var data = localStorageData==null?[]:localStorageData;
```

Then check for the the values presented in the array and `check/uncheck` checkboxe's :

```
if(data.indexOf(objs[i]) >= 0)
    cElement.checked = true;
else
    cElement.checked = false;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: mind put it in on the plnkr? `this.checked` condition is showing an error `:` unexpected token

Comment: Nvm about the unexpected token I was just being blind, although it should be `this.checked ? 'block' : 'none'`

Comment: Yes my bad it just a typo (fixed).

Comment: Doesn't seems to be doing anything :/

Comment: is it possible to put them in array when you untick them?

Comment: Though when you refresh the page the checkbox returns to `true` state, should be untick when its saved on localStorage? How can I put it to `false` so its untick when its in the localStorage?

Comment: Ok, show me the way you stored the info in localstorage.

Comment: Check my updated answer and this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/217/

Answer (score 1):

You'd add an event handler that does something to the input when the checkbox is checked

```js
function dynamicStuff() {
    var objs = ['Id', 'Name', 'Age'];

    for (var j = 0; j < objs.length; j++) {
     (function(i) {
            objs[i];

            var cElementInput = document.createElement("input");
            cElementInput.type = "text";
            cElementInput.name = objs[i];
            cElementInput.id = objs[i];
            cElementInput.placeholder = objs[i];

            var cElement = document.createElement("input");
            cElement.type = "checkbox";
            cElement.name = objs[i];
            cElement.id = objs[i];
            cElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
             cElementInput.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'inline';
                localStorage.setItem(objs[i], this.value);
            });
            
            var br = document.createElement('br');

            document.getElementById('chkBox').appendChild(cElement);
            document.getElementById('chkBox').appendChild(cElementInput);
            document.getElementById('chkBox').appendChild(br);
            document.getElementById('chkBox').appendChild(br.cloneNode());
        })(j);
    }

}

dynamicStuff()
```

```html
<div id="chkBox"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why did you wrap the `obj[]` in a func `(function(i) {}`

Comment: Because I'm using `objs[i]` inside the event handler, and that means I also need a closure to keep the value of `i` from not changing with the loop.